# problem in app-simple player

Tags: python, application-development

File "/home/rohit/rohit-player/rohit_player/RohitPlayerWindow.py", line 54, in on_open_clicked
    media_files.append({"File":f, "uri":file_uri, "format":format})
NameError: global name 'media_files' is not defined

i have followed line by line tutorial of rick ! on building a simple player

{http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/multimedia/creating-a-simple-media-player/}

but i am stuck on the above mentioned error 
when i click on open button to select files it just show up on terminal ("the above mentioned error")
i have till now worked till displaying the list to user
i m on 12.04 lts!
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that tutorial is now out of date and won't work with the current Quickly. We are currently working to get it updated. I recommend you instead follow the video at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ for how to get started with our current developer platform.